# Автозаполнение массива

Tags: java, массивы

Допустим, я создаю строковый одномерный массив. В дальнейшем к каждому его элементу мне нужно будет прибавить другую строку. Получается я буду прибавлять к null, а не к пустой строки. Можно ли сразу присвоить всем элементам пустые строки, не инициализируя каждый элемент в цикле for. Вопрос из любопытства и поиска компактного кода.

Comment: что за язык на котором вы того, массив...?

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл уточнить, java

Answer (score 1):

Добавил присвоение пустой строки элементу в цикле перед конкатенацией, все работает.

Comment: Если есть какой-то волшебный метод присваивающий всем элементам определенное значение - готов узнать

Comment: `java.util.Arrays#fill(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Для заполнения массива одинаковыми значениями можно использовать метод [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object)):

```java
String[] arr = new String[5];

// заполняем массив пустыми строками
Arrays.fill(arr, "");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [, , , , ]
```